# Two Yii2 applications Login conflict

Tags: authentication, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have two different Yii2 Basic template applications on the same hosting. When I login to the first Yii2 app and then go to login the secon Yii2 app, the first automatically logs out and vice versa. They use different cookieValidationKey in config. How to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it fixes your problem but try to change configuration for `identityCookie` in one of the applications.

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'user' => [
        // ...
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_identity', // <-- change _identity to something else
            'httpOnly' => true
        ]
    ]
]
```